# Wait until Isolate port listener have finished in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates

I'm running code in a Flutter Isolate to work with images. To get the result from the isolate to the main thread, I'm listening to the port. This looks like that:

```
List imageReferences = List<Map>[];
 
for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  print("Spwarn Isolate");
  final flutterIsolate =
      await FlutterIsolate.spawn(compressImageAndCreateThumbs, images[i]);

  final receivePort = ReceivePort();
  final sendPort = receivePort.sendPort;
  IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping('compressImageAndCreateThumbs');
  IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
      sendPort, 'compressImageAndCreateThumbs');

  receivePort.listen((dynamic compressedImageList) async {
    print("Get Result from Isolate");
    Uint8List compressedImageBytes = compressedImageList[0];
    Uint8List thumbnailImageBytes = compressedImageList[1];

    var imageReference = await MyStorage()
        .uploadEntryImage(compressedImageBytes, images.length);

    var thumbnailReference =
        await MyStorage().uploadEntryThumbnail(thumbnailImageBytes);

    imageReferences
        .add({"image": imageReference, "thumb": thumbnailReference});
    flutterIsolate.kill();
  });
}

print(imageReferences); // This is called first and the result is: [] because the listener duration is longer
```

I have a async problem here. Because the `receivePort.listener` calls asynchronous, the line `print(imageReferences);` is calling first. But thats a problem because here I need all the data from the finished for loop.

Do I have the possibility to wait until I got all data from the listeners? I think about a following syntax (just an example with `Completer`):

```
Completer _completer = Completer();

List imageReferences = List<Map>[];

for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  // Do stuff with images
  receivePort.listen((dynamic compressedImageList) async {
    imageReferences.add({"image": "test", "thumb": "test"});

    if (i == images.length) {
      _completer.complete(); // When I pass the last element, set the _completer to complete()
    }
  });
}

await Future.wait(_completer.isCompleted()); // Wait until the _completer is completed. Then go!
print(imageReferences); // Now I have all data stored here
```

Do exists such a workflow? If not, what could I do here?

Comment: `await _completer.future`

Comment: Woaaa.. that's the magic?!

Comment: that is what `Completer` is for :-)

Comment: Now the world makes sense.... :-) Many thanks! Thats so easy!

Comment: btw you can also do `completer.complete(some result)` and then `result = await completer.future` - that way you can pass the result directly via `Future`